# Pandas corr() vs corrwith()

Tags: python, pandas

What is the reason of Pandas to provide two different correlation functions?

> **DataFrame.corrwith(other, axis=0, drop=False)**: 
>   Correlation between rows or columns of two DataFrame objectsCompute pairwise

vs.

> **DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)**: Compute pairwise
>   correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values

(from pandas 0.20.3 documentation)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first one computes correlation with another dataframe:

> between rows or columns of two DataFrame objects

The second one computes it with itself

> Compute pairwise correlation of columns

Answer (score 21):

**Basic Answer:**

Here's an example that might make it more clear:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df1=pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(3,2), columns=list('ab') )
df2=pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(3,2), columns=list('ac') )
```

As noted by @ffeast, use `corr` to compare numerical columns within the same dataframe.  Non-numerical columns will automatically be skipped.

```
df1.corr()

          a         b
a  1.000000 -0.840475
b -0.840475  1.000000
```

You can compare columns of df1 & df2 with `corrwith`.  Note that only columns with the **same names** are compared:

```
df1.corrwith(df2)

a    0.993085
b         NaN
c         NaN
```

**Additional options:**

If you want pandas to ignore the column names and just compare the first row of df1 to the first row of df2, then you could rename the columns of df2 to match the columns of df1 like this:

```
df1.corrwith(df2.set_axis( df1.columns, axis='columns', inplace=False))

a    0.993085
b    0.969220
```

Note that df1 and df2 need to have the same number of columns in that case.

Finally, a kitchen sink approach:  you could also simply horizontally concatenate the two datasets and then use `corr()`.  The advantage is that this basically works regardless of the number of columns and how they are named, but the disadvantage is that you might get more output than you want or need:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).corr()

          a         b         a         c
a  1.000000 -0.840475  0.993085 -0.681203
b -0.840475  1.000000 -0.771050  0.969220
a  0.993085 -0.771050  1.000000 -0.590545
c -0.681203  0.969220 -0.590545  1.000000
```

Comment: Ahhh!! Your last hint "same name" is quite usefull. This is where I got confused, because I somehow did not realized the logic, which columns are correlated.

Comment: @BaluJr.  yeah, I did that intentionally b/c often people assume that pandas will align the columns by location (including me ;-) but pandas generally does thing by label.