# correlation of two column values

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a dataframe called df(please refer the figure given)
I want the correlation between A1&A2 in separate column A3.

Code I have written:
I have created new column A3 to my dataframe

```
df['A3']=df['A1'].corr(df['A2'])
```

with the above I am getting incorrect correlation value

t
[image]

Comment: I think you should use df.corr() to check the correlation between A1 and A2.... Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041148/pandas-corr-vs-corrwith

Comment: Where is `df['A3']` in the figure ?

Comment: sorry I did not mention it but I can able to add a new column with the below code  df["A3"] = ""